# Django rest API Framework : Serializer use dynamically

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a framework using Django rest API.
I want to configure Serializer fields and Name of class variable of serializer dynamically using a factory pattern. My code is a bit complex so here is the simplified version of problem.

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class FixedSrializer(serializers.Serializer): 
    email= serializers.EmailField()

fixed_serializer=FixedSrializer(data={"email":"invalidemail"})
fixed_serializer.errors  
#OUTPUT: {'email': [u'Enter a valid email address.']}

# Trying Above  by dynamically assigning class var 

class CustomSrializer(serializers.Serializer):
    pass # no class var assigned

#setattr(CustomSrializer,"email",serializers.EmailField()) 
CustomSrializer.email=serializers.EmailField()
custom_serializer=CustomSrializer(data={"email":"invalidemail"})
custom_serializer.errors  
#OUTPUT# {}
#EXPECTED# {'email': [u'Enter a valid email address.']}
```

I think this may be because of dynamically changing class variable. Please correct where I am doing wrong.

If you see my post a bit carefully 1) FixedSrializer => contains email fields 2) CustomSrializer. Does not contain email field but in very next line assigned. Rest every thing is same for both and I am getting different outputs.I am using django-rest-framework.org.

Comment: Can you specify what error/s (if any) you are getting when you run the code?

Comment: Joe I am not getting any error. I just want to know why this code is not working as expected.

Comment: If there are no errors (runtime ones) then there must be logic errors (or something else). Can you specify what the code "is supposed to do" as opposed to what "it is doing" ?

Comment: If you see my post a bit carefully 1) FixedSrializer => contains email fields 2) CustomSrializer. Does not contain email field but in very next line assigned.    Rest every thing is same for both and I am getting different outputs.I am using http://www.django-rest-framework.org/.

Comment: Giving a hunch, in this [code](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L225), I see a comment: `get_fields` : `Returns the complete set of fields for the object as a dict, this will be the set of any explicitly declared fields`. So I feel their query considers only fields explicitly set in the class.

Comment: SO is any way to achieve the same ?